# Javascript for in error trying to extract the max value in obj1

Tags: javascript

The code of `.html` file is here:

```
<script>
n={}
obj1={}
obj1[Math.random()]={x:2}
obj1[Math.random()]={x:4}
obj1[Math.random()]={x:6}
for(i1 in obj1){for(i2 in obj1){if(obj1[i1].x>obj1[i2].x){max=obj1[i1].x}else{max=obj1[i2].x}}}
document.write(max)
</script>
```

When I execute that, the value that is written into the document is 6.

I change into this:

```
<script>
n={}
obj1={}
obj1[Math.random()]={x:2}
obj1[Math.random()]={x:6}
obj1[Math.random()]={x:4}
for(i1 in obj1){for(i2 in obj1){if(obj1[i1].x>obj1[i2].x){max=obj1[i1].x}else{max=obj1[i2].x}}}
document.write(max)
</script>
```

The value is 4...

Explain me which is the moment when `obj1[i1].x` is larger than `obj1[i2].x`. This is very weird, because I changed to obj[i1] and I not defined the obj1[Math.random()] object and this give me an error

> max is not defined

What? If I say `max=obj1[i1].x`, again `max=obj1[i1].x`, **AGAIN**`max=obj1[i1].x` . What could 5 are smaller than 3??

Obviously, I want to get running my program and give the greatest obj1's x, but the javascript doesn't behave.

Comment: The first thing I'd do is add some console.log statements inside the for loops to see how many object properties you are picking up. It might be more than just the properties you've created.

Comment: have you considered prettifying your source to make it more readable?

Comment: well, you'll always get whatever the last value is as the answer ... because the last iteration compares the last property with the last property ... and assign max to the value of the last property

Comment: @JaromandaX X
Now I see that your comments are less readable than my question...

Comment: @RobZuber
Yes, and it's weird because it give me the correct X, but when I compare then, the conditional apparently get the **SMALLER** value when the navigator want.

Comment: @CristianMartínezVillarejo - I'm a big fan of one liner code too ... `var max = Math.max.apply(Math, Object.values(obj1).map(v => v.x))`

Comment: @JaromandaX

Yes, and you should be a fan of omission of `var` and `;`, because the `

` (Intro) character acts in javascript as the same as `;`, and javascript is maded for convert cons to vars when I apply an operation.

Comment: @JaromandaX

I don't want to be rude. I just want to know when the comparison fails and get the smaller number. Help me please.

Comment: you seem to have figured it out yourself anyway :p

Comment: Where is the problemm?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally got the solution:

```html
<script>
aux1=0
aux2=0
obj={}
length=20
for(i=0;i<length;i++){
 obj[i]=Math.floor(Math.random()*10)
}
for(i in obj){
 for(j in obj){
  if(obj[j]<obj[eval(j)+1]){
   aux1=obj[j]
   aux2=obj[eval(j)+1]
   obj[eval(j)+1]=aux1
   obj[j]=aux2
  }
 }
}
for(i in obj){
 document.write(obj[i])
}
alert("max is "+obj[0])
</script>
```

And another solution is:

```html
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
    prev=0
    obj1={}
    obj1[Math.random()]={x:2}
    obj1[Math.random()]={x:4}
    obj1[Math.random()]={x:6}
    max=-Infinity
    for(i1 in obj1){if(obj1[i1].x>max){max=obj1[i1].x}}
    document.write(max)
    </script>
```

Comment: The 'solution' on top fails and is once again order dependent... The idea here is to only grab each object once and find the max of all three... Your top solution breaks if the order is x:8, x:2, x:4 because prev goes from 8, to 2 then to 4. And when it is 2 4 > 2 therefore the answer for the loop is 4... I agree with a commenter if you want this to be a one line code use this:
var max = Math.max.apply(null, Object.values(obj1).map(v => v.x)
Otherwise I would stick with the '-Infinity' trick...

Comment: Nope. The solution on top breaks, but the solution in bottom doesn't, because it's a prepared solution.

Comment: Sorry my arrogancy & blindness, I repared my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are reassigning max each time. Your code should look more like this:

```
var max = -Infinity;
for(var i1 in obj1){if(obj1[i1].x>max){max=obj1[i1].x}}
```

This will save you loops time and give you the expected result. Otherwise max was the max of the last comparison performed.

Comment: >Uncaught ReferenceError: max is not defined

Comment: @CristianMartínezVillarejo It is no more incomplete than your initial code. I could write it to be cleaner and more correct (strict typing etc), but I was trying to give you lines to copy and paste.

Comment: Nope, the best answer is my answer, because has got two solution. One in the top that "breaks", and one in the bottom that I tried and it doesn't break.